How can I evaluate $ \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(2e^x-1)}{e^x-1} dx $ using Feynman's trick?
I would like to find out a solution using just Feynman's method and Calculus I basic methods, to share with a novice student. I have found at Quora and this site some solutions containing transcendental functions and infinite series, which may not help so much in this case.

Do you have reason t9 believe this integral has a closed form, or that Feynman's method can be used on this integral?

And if you've found the value on this site, link to one, and tell us what you know.

According to Wolfram, it has a closed form

This question here has an answer that uses the Leibniz integral rule for differentiating under the integral sign.

The YouTube channel Maths 505 did a great video on this exact question, you can find his solution here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayls_5VjcXQ
